# A Stack Exchange site is wrongly saying it hasn't been created yet

Tags: support, stack-exchange, 500-server-error

The [Biostar Stack Exchange](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/) is currently showing a confused panda and saying

> Couldn't find
>   biostar.stackexchange.com
>
> The Q&A site biostar.stackexchange.com
>   doesn't seem to exist…yet.
>
> You can vote for it to be created
>   through our democratic,
>   community-driven process at
>   area51.stackexchange.com, or see a
>   complete directory of all our Q&A
>   sites at stackexchange.com.
>
> If you are the administrator of a
>   Stack Exchange 1.0 site, please
>   contact Robert Cartaino with any
>   questions you may have.

Biostar existed previously, so the error message is incorrect.

**Update**: OK, so it seems to be a Stack Exchange 1.0 site, but if I got confused, so will a lot of other people. It doesn't explicitly say that there may have been a SE 1.0 site that has since been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Biostar existed previously, so the error message is incorrect.

More or less, although they shared the same name, stackexchange 1.0 was different than stackexchange 2.0

Comment: How do I tell whether Biostar was a stack exchange 1.0 site?

Comment: You said yourself it existed before, if it did at biostar.stackexchange.com, it was a SE 1.0 site.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141143/the-website-biostar-stackexchange-com-has-been-disabled/141688#141688