# Is Homebrew.SE in private beta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, 500-server-error

I got an email today announcing that https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/ was open in private beta.  However, when I try to go there, I see a sad panda (or confused, or embarrassed, I'm not really sure).

[image: panda]

So, is the site up yet?  Is this just a hiccup in the process?  Should I try again tomorrow?

This sounds like what was happening with biostar.SE, as described in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69745/a-stack-exchange-site-is-wrongly-saying-it-hasnt-been-created-yet), but that site seems to be working now.  Also, homebrew.SE was never a 1.0 site, so I don't think this is the same problem, just a similar result.

Comment: +1 for including the picture. I'm so lazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We screwed up the DNS on this. We'll be emailing everyone again tomorrow. Sorry about that.

Comment: No wonder the Panda looked confused :)

Comment: Is there a chance meta is still affected? I'm having login issues

Comment: @Joe Phillips: Yes, it appears to be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69755/meta-keeps-logging-me-out-of-parent

Answer (score 2):

I had to put an entry in my hosts file (rchern=awesome) for it to work but I was having the same problem earlier today.

Comment: +1 for using a hosts entry.

Comment: What a good idea. (;

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me. Have you tried a [hard refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)?

Comment: It's going to depend on what your upstream servers have if they still have the bad entry in cache you're going to have to wait it out.