# Meta keeps logging me out of parent

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

For the new homebrew private beta site, I am successfully logged in and then when I go to meta it recognizes me at first, logs me in, and then refreshes and I'm logged out again. When I go to parent I've also been logged out there. I have no way of logging into meta right now.

I've just tried clearing my cache/cookies and it keeps doing the same thing.

Comment: See also: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/144/cant-login-to-meta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are major problems with DNS right now on that site. You'll need to sit tight for 24 hours.