# Error accessing chat on Apple.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, ask-different

This is best described by a screenshot from the right hand side of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/is-there-a-hard-keyboard-case-for-the-ipad-keyboard) page:

[image]

There seems to be something wrong here. On other SE sites, that area lists active chat rooms and users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69755/meta-keeps-logging-me-out-of-parent/69763#69763) [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69749/is-homebrew-se-in-private-beta/69752#69752) side effect of some DNS snafu-ery.

When DNS shakes out, the chat "ad" will begin working again.

Chat itself is unaffected.