# Where is BioStar?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Stack Exchange site is wrongly saying it hasn't been created yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69745/a-stack-exchange-site-is-wrongly-saying-it-hasnt-been-created-yet)

What happened to BioStar (a site focused on bioinformatics and computational biology)? Is it closed now?

Comment: no, it was gone yesterday afternoon PST, returned in the evening, and is now unavailable again.

Comment: Hmm, it is available to me (and I was able to visit it just fine when that other question was posted, too).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried flushing your DNS? What are your DNS server setting? Are you getting the "sad panda" or a page cannot be found?

I've checked against Google and OpenDNS they both are returning the correct result, and it works for me.

Google:

```
[gbeech@ny-exdns01 ~]$ dig @8.8.8.8 biostar.stackexchange.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_4.2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 biostar.stackexchange.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33762
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;biostar.stackexchange.com.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
biostar.stackexchange.com. 18701 IN     A       64.34.80.165

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov  9 18:46:52 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59

[gbeech@ny-exdns01 ~]$
```

OpenDNS:

```
[gbeech@ny-exdns01 ~]$ dig @208.67.222.222 biostar.stackexchange.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_4.2 <<>> @208.67.222.222 biostar.stackexchange.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21236
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;biostar.stackexchange.com.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
biostar.stackexchange.com. 3350 IN      A       64.34.80.165

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov  9 18:47:39 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59

[gbeech@ny-exdns01 ~]$
```

My Record:

```
[gbeech@ny-exdns01 ~]$ dig @localhost biostar.stackexchange.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_4.2 <<>> @localhost biostar.stackexchange.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25456
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;biostar.stackexchange.com.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
biostar.stackexchange.com. 21600 IN     A       64.34.80.165
```