# Login on BioStar with Stack Exchange 2.0 username and password?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-exchange, display-names, password

I often use Stack Overflow, Tex.StackExchange, and most of all [BioStar](http://www.biostars.org/about/). But on BioStar I cannot login with my Stack Exchange username and password. Why?

Could you please change BioStar settings and allow users to login with their Stack Exchange login details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confused about biostar, 1.0, 2.0 isn't SE a big family?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93004/confused-about-biostar-1-0-2-0-isnt-se-a-big-family)

Comment: @Brandon A helpful explanation of BioStar, but certainly not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized for being obsolete: BioStar is no longer a Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 5):

[BioStar](https://biostar.stackexchange.com/) was a Stack Exchange 1.0 site. Before Stack Exchange operated the current network of sites it allowed others to license the software and run their own sites. BioStar is not part of the Stack Exchange network and now runs their own Q&A software.

See [this discussion on BioStar about the possibility of them joining the Stack Exchange network](https://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/13915/should-biostar-be-switched-over-to-the-stackexchange-network), although at this point I'd be surprised (it's been a long time since an SE1.0 site has joined).

That notwithstanding, you can still use your Stack Exchange OpenID login by manually entering its OpenID URL on the BioStar login screen:

[image]

*edit:* At least in theory... I'm getting an error when I try.

Comment: Thanx a lot. For the login, I've tried with my OpenId http://DavideChicco.it.stackexchange.com/ or syonyms http://DavesYourFriend.stackexchange.com/ or user number http://user1082019.stackexchange.com/ but it does not work... how can I do?

Comment: @DavideChicco.it I'm not sure... The URL `http://openid.stackexchange.com/` works on other OpenID sites, but doesn't seem to work on SE1.0 sites. Perhaps SE1.0 only supports OpenID v1, but Stack Exchange's OpenID is only v2. If this is correct, you're out of luck.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it those are not valid urls you are trying.   `openid.stackexchange.com`, with no protocol, with http, and with https...all 3 work just fine for me on biostar.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Strange... that just worked for me now, but it didn't work either of the times I tried earlier. It was able to confirm my login on Stack Exchange, but when I was redirected back to BioStar it gave me an error. I auto-completed the same URL, so I know that didn't change. My IP has changed, but I'd be surprised if that were it. *(edit: Oops, didn't mean to use this account.)*